# Access DataTemplate in ResourceDictionary in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, datatemplate, resourcedictionary

I've defined a DataTemplate in a ResourceDictionary 'style1.xaml':

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >

    <DataTemplate x:Key="BlogDataTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,6,20" Width="400" Height="210">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="#A6000000">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Foreground="White" Margin="6" FontSize="25" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

While in the App.xaml.cs, I use the following code to merge the ResourceDictionary:

```
void LoadDictionary()
{
    var dictionaries = Resources.MergedDictionaries;
    string source = string.Empty;
    var themeStyles = new ResourceDictionary { };
    switch (Settings.fontStyle.Value)
    {
        case 0:
            source = String.Format("/app;component/Themes/style1.xaml");
            themeStyles.Source = new Uri(source, UriKind.Relative);
            dictionaries.Add(themeStyles);
            break;
        case 1:
            source = String.Format("/app;component/Themes/style2.xaml");
            themeStyles.Source = new Uri(source, UriKind.Relative);
            dictionaries.Add(themeStyles);
            break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

With debugging I can make sure that the style1.xaml had been merged, then in the MainPage.xmal I have a Listbox, I define the ItemTemplate as

```
 <ListBox x:Name="listbox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" CacheMode="BitmapCache" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BlogDataTemplate}"/>
```

But when I deployed the app, it caused a "Unspecified error ".

So how to access DataTemplate in ResourceDictionary in Windows Phone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the LoadDictionary code, try merging the ResourceDictionary with Xaml in App.xaml by doing something like (in App.xaml, in Application.Resources):

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/style1.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Hi codechinchilla,
I did what you have posted in your answer but it throws exception can not find resource with name/key BlogDataTemplate how to get rid of this exception?

Comment: Hey Android_Crazy - can you post your App.xaml and the resource dictionary xaml you are using?

Comment: For the community, how did you go about solving your problem?  Thanks.